# pg_dump with Django: -o flag needed?

Tags: django, postgresql

When using `pg_dump` to dump a postgres database that is being used as the back-end for a Django application. Do I need to use the "-o" flag (dump object identifiers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Postgres 8.1 or greater, then no - not unless you are tying into your system tables somehow. OIDs in postgres are only used for system tables unless `WITH OIDS` is specified when the user table is created.

[OIDs in postgres docs.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-oid.html)

`WITH OIDS` used to be the default in Postgres 8.0 and prior, but that has been switched in Postgres 8.1.